# how to use `if` worksheet function in vba?

Tags: excel, vba

My code is as follows:

```
Function my_if() As Boolean
    my_if = Application.WorksheetFunction.If(True, True, False)
End Function
```

But I am getting `#VALUE` as a result. Why is that?

Comment: According to MSDN there is no If method in WorksheetFunction. See: [https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/excel.worksheetfunction.ifna]. Use IIF instead: [https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/language/reference/user-interface-help/iif-function]

Comment: @PéterForgó thanks, the links not working because of the excessive brackets

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`If` isn't one of the functions in the `WorksheetFunction` object. Rather than writing your own `my_if` function, just use the built-in VBA function `IIF` instead. Or, you could do:

```
Function my_if() As Boolean
    my_if = IIf(True, True, False)
End Function
```